# How to pick a random sample of given size from a set of unknown size

Tags: probability, sampling

I have the following problem: I'm reading huge amounts of data records; when done, I would like to display one or more randomly selected records from the data set. It's easy to do if I can cache the data—in that case, it boils down to selecting a few random indexes. It is also easy if I know whether I will get to see a hundred or a million records.

But I don't know how many records I will get to see before the file has been read completely, so it would appear that I'll have to adjust the likelihood of picking a given record as time passes.

Surely, when I'm asked to display three random entries and I'm just reading the first, second or third record, the probability $p$ of displaying them should be be 1—after all, in case the data file ends at that point, that's the bes$ i can do.

And indeed, [according to xkcd, that's already good enough.](http://xkcd.com/221/) on the downside, if I stop just there, I will always see the same sample when I read the same data again. So on reading the fourth record, there should be a probability $\le1$ that I have to replace any one of the records in the display list with the fourth record. But if I keep $p$ at 1 or very close, then subsequent records will dominate the results.

Is this possible to do? Maybe there's a practical approximation for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to find $n$ random samples from the entire file, and you have already read $m\ge n$ data points and selected $n$ samples among those in a way that we will assume is uniform.

Now you see sample number $m+1$. If the file ended here, the sample you just saw should be in the output with probability $\frac{n}{m+1}$. Make a random choice with that probability. If it comes out false, you do nothing. Otherwise, *evict a random one* among the $n$ saved samples from the first $m$ positions and overwrite it with data item $m+1$.

It should be clear that the $n-1$ samples that *don't* get evicted forms a uniformly chosen set of $n-1$ samples from the first $m$ ones. So when you do chose to use data point number $m+1$ you get a uniform distribution among all size-$n$ sets that satisfy that choice. And otherwise you already have an uniformly chosen set of $n$ points that *doesn't* contain item $m+1$. So, all in all, you now have a uniformly chosen set of $n$ among the $m+1$ first data items.

Proceed by induction until you reach the end of the file.

Comment: if anyone can confirm that both H.M.'s and H.v.E.'s solution are correct, i will randomly select one of them as the correct answer as they both wrote at the same moment.

Comment: @flow: Actually I had him beat by 22 seconds. But since our presentations are in quite different styles, it should be possible for you to select the one you find clearest, rather than just drawing lots. (And you have enough rep to upvote in any case).

Comment: accepted for being the first (and correct, i believe)

Answer (score 1):

1. Assign $s\leftarrow 0$ (the number of items "seen") and prepare an array to hold $n$ records $x_1,\ldots, x_n$
2. If there is no more input available, terminate: $x_1,\ldots x_n$ is your sample (provided $s\ge n$, as otherwise no such sample is possible)
3. Otherwise, read an item $x$ from input and let $s\leftarrow s+1$
4. If $s\le n$, let $x_s\leftarrow x$
5. Otherwise, let $p=\frac{n}{s}$. With probability $p$, do the following: Let $i$ be a random number uniformly picked from $1,\ldots,n$ and set $x_i\leftarrow x$
6. Go back to step 2

This generates up to two random numbers per loop and never stores more items than necessary for a sample. At any point during the process (once the initial $n$ items have been read), the array contains a valid sample of the input so far.

Comment: if anyone can confirm that both H.v.E.'s and H.M.'s solution are correct, i will randomly select one of them as the correct answer as they both wrote at the same moment.

Comment: upvoted for delivering a ready-to-type solution for a programmer's question.